# Including Javascript as a local resource in Xcode 4 while using a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode

I saw this question answered for Xcode 3, but Xcode 4 seems to have changed.

I am unable to figure out how to include a javascript file as a local resource for an iPhone App using UIWebView.  The compiler tries to interpret the included .js files as code rather than including them in the root app bundle as a resource for reference in an html file.

In my case specifically I was trying to include a local copy of a javascript file so the UIWebView portion of the app can perform certain functions while not connected to the internet, so I need a local copy....

Anyone have this figured out for Xcode 4?

Thanks
-Steve

Answer (score 4):

Wow.  Spent hours trying to figure it out, so I finally posted the question.  10 minutes later I run across a totally unrelated thread that pointed me in the right direction.

In Xcode 4 in the Project Navigator click on the top item, the project, then select your Target and click on the Build Phases tab.  There is a Copy Bundle Resources in that window that will let you add the .js files you need in the local resources.  Now all html references such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourAwesomeCode.js"></script>
```

will work

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work for you?  Works great for me.  ?

Answer (score 1):

@gcamp is right, but he forgot to mention that when you call - loadHTMLString: or - loadRequest: . You must specify the baseURL to the URL of you bundle resource directory. like this

```
// load htmlString into web view
[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLString
        baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] isDirectory:YES]];
```

```